# Sandbox Login not working

Tags: apex, community, single-sign-on

We can't login to our eloqua sandbox. I get this error...

We can't log you in because you're only allowed to use single sign-on. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator.

SSO setting not enabled for both delegated or federated.

Comment: Are you a system administrator?

Answer (score 1):

This might have happened because SSO is enabled for System Administrator profiles. Remove SSO from those profiles in Production and refresh the sandbox. That may solve your problem.